# Ember js - send request and receive response from backend java server

Tags: ember.js

I have build my backend using java and the datas will be returned in json format.
Using ember as frontend, how do I send request and receive response to fetch the data from server.
Im completely new to ember and expecting some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is probably to read / follow the [Ember.JS tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/), so you'll learn Ember.JS basis before working with dynamic data.

If you already know Ember.JS basis and want to go further with dynamic data, I'll recommend you to read :

1/ [Ember.JS Tutorial : Working with data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/working-with-data/)

It'll give you some details for handling dynamic data, without using Ember Data.

2/ [Ember.JS Tutorial : Ember Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-2/ember-data/)

> Ember Data is built around the idea of organizing your app's data into model objects

3/ By default, Ember Data expects the server to send response using the [JSONApi](https://jsonapi.org/) specs.

If this is not your case, you'll have to [customize Ember Data to use another Adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/), probably the [RESTAdapter](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/RESTAdapter).

4/ Some further reading :

- [Ember Data Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/)
- [Ember Data API Doc](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release)